# The amount of gb mb kb and bytes in X bytes, java

Tags: java, byte, converters

Ok so I have this problem for my pg class, where I'm supposed to take a number(which represents a number of bytes) as input and convert it to gigabytes, megabytes, kilobytes and bytes. Did a little research and couldn't find a way to solve this. I'm using Java by the way. Thanks in advice!

```
Here is an example:
 Input  : 3434901120028
 Output : 3199 GB + 1001 KB + 28 bytes
```

Comment: You should've edited the post, not put the example in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of bytes divided by 1024 is the number of kilobytes. The number of kilobytes divided by 1024 is the number of megabytes. That divided by 1024 is the number of gigabytes. Something like,

```
long bytes = 3434901120028l;
long gb = bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
bytes -= gb * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
long mb = bytes / (1024 * 1024);
bytes -= mb * 1024 * 1024;

long kb = bytes / 1024;
bytes -= kb * 1024;

if (gb > 0) {
    System.out.printf("%d gigabytes ", gb);
}
if (mb > 0) {
    System.out.printf("%d megabytes ", mb);
}
if (kb > 0) {
    System.out.printf("%d kilobytes ", kb);
}
if (bytes > 0) {
    System.out.printf("%d bytes ", bytes);
}
```

Output is

```
3199 gigabytes 1001 kilobytes 28 bytes
```

Comment: should be double or floats. You're losing precision at each step because you put the result in a int.

Comment: i know that part but how do i get for example 3434901120028 and get the gb + mb + kb + bytes in this case it would be smthing like 
3199 GB + 1001 KB + 28 bytes

Comment: one final question can u explain this line i get everything expect for that step bytes -= gb * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

Comment: Subtract the number of gigabytes from the number of bytes. Each gigabyte is 1024 meg; each meg is 1024 kb; each kb is 1024 bytes. That's `1024 * 1024 * 1024`.